# Should I declare swing components in my application final..?

Tags: java, swing, junit, awt, software-design

In my application i have many swing components.
Should i make these component variables final in my class and then instantiate in constructor or should i directly instantiate them without making them final.

```
public class MyClass 
{
    private final JFrame firstFrame;
    private final JPanel firstPanel;
    private final JButton firstButton;

    public MyClass()
    {
        firstFrame = new JFrame();
        firstPanel = new JPanel();
        firstJButton = new JButton();
    }
}
```

is this approach better taking into consideration design and optimization or the below one is better.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void createGUI()
    {
        private JFrame firstFrame = new JFrame();
        private JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
        private JButton firstJButton = new JButton();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second snippet is incorrect you cannot have the private keyword inside of a method.

With regards to your question, if the variable is not accessed by another method then it should not be global. You should declare it inside of the method in which it is used.

If a variable is not modified you should add the final keyword.

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't intend on initializing your swing components *more than once*, then you can use the **final** modifier to make this clear. This will prevent the components from being reassigned.

You can't have a private modifier within the scope of a method, the only modifier permitted in method scope is the **final** modifier. For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void createGUI()
    {
        final JFrame firstFrame = new JFrame();
        final JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
        final JButton firstJButton = new JButton();
    }
}
```

However, I prefer the example:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    private final JFrame firstFrame;
    private final JPanel firstPanel;
    private final JButton firstButton;

    public MyClass()
    {
        firstFrame = new JFrame();
        firstPanel = new JPanel();
        firstJButton = new JButton();
    }
}
```

This would ensure that the components cannot be reassigned and also provides instance-scope access to the components whereas in the first example, the scope is limited to the scope of the method `createGUI()`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that all instance veriables, defined in your class, will be initialize in your constructor and will not changed, you should select the `final` modifier.

In case your instance varible is not accesssed outside class , you can declare that `private`.

Your 1st code snippet is perfect but 2nd one will not even compile.