# Error in java calculator programme "Field '(button)' may be 'final'

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am creating gui calculator in **Java**

I am using IDEA

programme runs successfully but it shows an error that Field '(any field)' may be 'final'......

I don't know what it is

[Here is image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE5BC.png)

Comment: It is not *error* (otherwise your code wouldn't run) but information that you can make those fields `final`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I declare swing components in my application final..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617772/should-i-declare-swing-components-in-my-application-final)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a warning/information message telling you that these variables are better to be declared as `final`. Whenever your IDE finds cases where you have not assigned anything to a variable, except at the time of initialization, it may give you such a warning/information message so that you can consider adjusting the code if required. I believe, you already understand [the concept of the keyword, `final` in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655012/how-does-the-final-keyword-in-java-work-i-can-still-modify-an-object).